# Post MVC form calling a controller action view that requires a viewmodel. Why does the ViewModel not get sent to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC `BeginForm` element that posts to a controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormViewModel Model)
{
     ... Some form saving logic
     return View()
}
```

But when the index view gets rendered I get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

My index view is like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...Create The IndexViewModel 
    return View(ViewModel)
}
```

How can I get the controller action to get called to generate the view model after the post?

If I call the Index Controller action from the HTTP Create like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormViewModel Model)
{
     ... Some form saving logic
     return Index()
}
```

I'll get a 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'IndexViewModel' , but this dictionary requires a model item of type `CreateViewModel`.

The Views reference the models associated with the controller actions that pass the arguments to the views.

Comment: `IndexViewModel` and `FormViewModel` are 2 different things. Show the views for `Index` and `Create`

Comment: You want to see the code for the views?  They basically just call the model like in the case of Create, '@model Project.ViewModels.CreateViewModel' and in the case of Index, '@model Project.ViewModels.IndexViewModel'.  The views render correctly when called from the urls, but when I post the Create Form I get the error when it tries to navigate back to the index.

Comment: You not navigating back to `Index()`! In the first snippet you do not return the model (your obviously trying to access a property of the model in the view but you won't show it so hard to tell exactly what your doing wrong). In the 3rd snippet, it you want to redirect, then you need `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Comment: You rock.  If you want to add an answer with that code snippet I will accept it.  I'll upvote your comment, anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet, you are not returning the model (the model will be null so accessing a property of the model (e.g. `<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>` will throw an exception)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormViewModel model)
{
    ... Some form saving logic
    return View(model); // change this so you return the model to the view
}
```

In the 3rd snippet, it you want to redirect to the index method, it needs to be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormViewModel Model)
{
    ... Some form saving logic
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); // Change this to redirect to the Index() method
}
```